# Aurelia to return alternative view for viewmodule only if the view exist

Tags: aurelia

Do the aurelia framework provide a way to check whether a view exists?

```
ViewLocator.prototype.convertOriginToViewUrl = (origin) => {

    let device = 'mobile';

    let moduleId = origin.moduleId.replace('.js', '').replace('.ts', '');      

    let deviceView = `${moduleId}-${device}.html`;

    //check if view exist and return if so
    if (ViewExist(deviceView)) {
        return deviceView;
    }

    //return default view
    return `${moduleId}.html`;
}

function ViewExist(view): boolean {
    //check filessytem?
    //check app-bundle?
    //any available api in aurelia to check?
    return false;

}
```

I've tried to use HttpClient from aurelia-fetch-client, but I guess because of the bundling of the files into app-bundle this option is not possible.

```
let http = new HttpClient();
let response = http.fetch('view-mobile.html');
```

Comment: You are right, the modules are bundled and unless you explicitly upload them to you server you won't be able to fetch them. Also as they are already bundled going to the server would be lost of time and bandwidth.

You should use the aurelia loader to check if the module exists. Check this gist out and let us know if it solves your problem:

https://gist.github.com/shanonvl/168ad247c868393b5d4c

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own view locator and replace the one framework uses

https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/7693dbd65e59e428e4052922920145b76240f3cf/src/view-locator.js

You can do that by Injecting your viewLocator in DI container

Also check the docs on customizing conventions
http://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/app-configuration-and-startup#customizing-conventions